# How can I use spring-cloud-zookeeper-discovery in cas-overlay-5.1.x

Tags: java, cas

I want to register the CAS as a Microservice to ZK,
there is my setting in `application.properties`

```
spring.application.name=aep-casserver
spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.enabled=true
spring.cloud.zookeeper.connect-string=127.0.0.1:2181
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.register=true
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-host=${LOCAL_IP}
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-port=${server.port}
spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-id=${spring.application.name}-${spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-host}:${spring.cloud.zookeeper.discovery.instance-port}
```

But no effect when I started the cas in tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation in your Application Class. Such as:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```